# Adding an object to a NSMutablearray doesn't work properly

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a situation where in a loop I'm trying to add an object to a NSMutableArray. At the end of the loop it is showing that 54 objects (as an example) are added to the array but when I'm trying to read the objects from the array, apparently they are all the same as each other and same as the last object that is inserted into the array.

Could anyone please help me with this issue.This is my code:

```
int counter=0;

for (int j=0; j<rows; j++) 
{      
     Product *product ;
     product = [[Product alloc] init];
     int numberr= [product getImageNumber];
     [wineList addObject:product];
     counter = counter + 1;  
}
```

After adding the objects,I'm testing the content of the array which I'm getting the same result for each item in the array

```
//testing
Product *producttest1 = wineList[1];
int numbertest1= [producttest1 getImageNumber];
Product *producttest2 = wineList[20];
int numbertest2= [producttest2 getImageNumber];
```

This is the definition of the `Product` class that I have :

```
#import "Product.h"
@implementation Product

int imageNumber;
bool isInCase;

-(id) init {
    imageNumber = (arc4random() % 11) + 1;

    isInCase = false;

    return self;
}

-(int) getImageNumber {

    return imageNumber;
}

-(void) setImageNumber:(int) number {

    imageNumber = number;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of getImageNumber?

Comment: when do you set imageNumber on the product object? I cant see any evidence that you are doing this.

Comment: What is getImageNumber function in your code ? Please post whole model class.

Comment: When I'm initialising the product,there is a property name ImageNumber which is set there with a random integer number.

Comment: I updated the question with the definition of the Product class.

Comment: Don't use "get" as a prefix. That should just be "imageNumber".

Comment: does it help with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `-init` method never initializes your class. Make a call to `[super init]`.

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        imageNumber = (arc4random() % 11) + 1;
        isInCase = false;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I did this but the problem is still there.

Comment: How exactly are you even checking to see if it "works"? Are you using the debugger to track down what is going on?

Comment: if you check the test section above, I added some code to check the value of two of the items in the array and it's showing that they both have the same value which is equal to the last item which is inserted into the array.

Comment: Just checking the result isn't enough. You need to use the debugger.

Comment: Try putting NSLog(@"number: %d",[product getImageNumber]); in your for loop, and lets us know if they are all the same numbers.

Comment: This is the result wich is showing the product is initialising correctly with different values but when we save them in the array,something else happens.

Comment: the result is :
2012-10-10 15:46:54.935 Cellar[97087:11303] number: 9

2012-10-10 15:46:55.582 Cellar[97087:11303] number: 5

2012-10-10 15:46:56.421 Cellar[97087:11303] number: 3

2012-10-10 15:47:07.275 Cellar[97087:11303] number: 7

Comment: And what if you use [wineList objectAtIndex:1] instead of wineList[1];

Comment: What is wrong with what you logged? Aren't you wanting them to log random numbers?

Comment: I want and it works fine but when I'm saving them in the array and then want to retrieve them from the array, all of the items in the array have the same number which means all the product objects in the array are the same.

Comment: Could you print the array and see if the pointers of all the objects are the same or not?

Comment: And maybe stupid question, but are you checking the right products, because I see a number 2 missing in the second product that you check.

Comment: Yes I'm printing the right one. sorry I corrected the variable name it was an hour old ;) but it's correct on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably go like this,

```
int counter=0;
for (int j=0; j < rows; j++) 
{      
     Product *product = [[Product alloc] init]; // Added variable declaration inside.
     int numberr= [product getImageNumber];
     [wineList addObject:product];
     [product release];                         // Added release for product
     counter = counter + 1;  

}
```

Comment: When I writting "[product release];" I'm getting this error: release is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: Ohh Yes.. ARC doesn't allow release statements. Does above for loop works without [product release]; statement ?